# Trim/Split the string

Tags: powershell, split, extract, trim

is it possible to extract in PowerShell the part of the string after second appearance of underscore ('_') ??

Input:

```
XXXXXX_YYYYYYYYYY_AAAAAA
WWWWWWWWWW_XXXXX_BBB
```

Needed Output:

```
AAAAAA    
BBB
```

Thank you for all advises,
Regards

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code, I have assigned 2 values to 2 variables and then performed split operation with '_' then taking the 3 value of that.

```
$a="XXXXXX_YYYYYYYYYY_AAAAAA"
$b="WWWWWWWWWW_XXXXX_BBB"
    
$a.Split('_')[2]

$b.Split('_')[2]
```

Output:

```
AAAAAA
BBB
```